# CSS Transform (Spin Animation) Glitching In Safari (iOS)

Tags: css, ios, macos, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a loader on my [website](https://dreamersabyss.com/) which is basically a logo spinning in 3D for a few seconds until the page is loaded. The loader works perfectly in all major browsers on android and Windows but, it glitches badly on iOS (in both Safari and Chrome).

[Glitch in Chrome on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFFIt.png)
[Glitch in Safari on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCfV6.jpg)

HTML:

```
<div id="loader">
    <div id="loader_spin_div" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" id="loader_spin" src="assets/img/Logo_329x329.webp" width="500"
        height="500" alt="Refresh Your Browser To See The Animation!">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loader {
    background: #ff9472;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

#loader_spin {
    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px -3px 48px 5px #fff;
    box-shadow: 11px -3px 48px 5px #fff;
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateY(179deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(1deg);
    }
}

#loader_spin_div {
    width: 18vh;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 18vh;
}

@media (min-width: 440px) {
    #loader_spin_div {
        width: 27vh;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the layering (z-index of the elements), which I read in another article.

Comment: That is because Safari is actually thinking in a real 3D space. Half of you image is disappearing behind the fully coloured pane. You will have to "lift" the element above the pane with something like transform: translate. 

Also note that Safari and Chrome are basically the same Browsers on iOS. Chrome is using the Safari render engine.

Comment: I tried using `transform: translateZ(100px);` but, it still didn't work...

Comment: You will have to set the parent to transform-style: preserve-3d; to make sure the "stage" is set the right way.

Comment: Sorry. While the explanation I gave was right, the solution was wrong. Please check my supposed solution underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari thinks in a real 3D space. The rotating image will go "through" the pane while rotating and half of it will not be visible. You will have to "lift" the parent container of the spinning image above the pane.

Bonus Tip: If you set the "perspective" you will get a real 3D effect.

See the following example - this will work in Safari:

```css
#loader {
    background: #ff9472;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    
}

#loader_spin {
    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 150px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px -3px 48px 5px #fff;
    box-shadow: 11px -3px 48px 5px #fff;
    transform-origin: center center;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate3d(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

#loader_spin_div {
    width: 18vh;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 18vh;
    transform: translateZ(100px) perspective(300px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    
}

@media (min-width: 440px) {
    #loader_spin_div {
        width: 27vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
    <div id="loader_spin_div" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="img-fluid mx-auto" id="loader_spin">
          The world goes round and round!        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks so much! Looks much better now